# Usage of "verfügen" with non-material entities

Tags: word-usage

How proper is it to use the verb *verfügen (über)* when relating to non-physical entities, such as mental abilities?

> Er verfügt über gute Sprachkenntnisse.
>
> Die Firma verfügt über das Urheberrecht dieses Produkts.
>
> Sie verfügt über hohen Grad von Empathie.

As can be seen in the examples, this can reach fairly abstact levels. [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/wb/verf%C3%BCgen) allows this generally. Still, how proper is it to use this verb very abstractly, in common and written language? I have some intuition that this verb has a rather materialistic "touch", I may of course be wrong. What would be good alternatives to it?

Comment: Just a comment to the use: In an formal text, I would write _Ich verfüge über gute Sprachkenntnisse in Englisch und Spanisch_ or _Sie verfügt über hohen Grad von Empathie_, in everyday conversation I would say _Ich spreche gut Englisch und Spanisch_ and _Sie ist sehr empathisch_.

Comment: All the three sentences are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown on the referenced website, "über etwas verfügen" (also) means "to have s.th.".
 There's absolutely nothing wrong when using it relating to non physical objects.
 On the contrary: Using "verfügen" instead of the simple "to have" gives your text/speech a more "intelligent" touch.

Comment: This is what I was aiming at – it's too easy to use _haben_ in such cases and I prefer the "intelligent" touch. I think the English parallel _possess_ seems to me intuitively to relate to material ownership. I'm not sure what an English native speaker would say about this, but I may have "übertragen" it to the German,

Comment: *Verfügen* literally means *to have command of* . *To have* is the shortened meaning, *To possess* is a derived one.